# How to make cell clickable also the buttons on cell will be clickable in swift

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I have used tableview in storyboard. in this tableview I have added cell.
each row cell contains labels and some buttons.

**Now:**

I want to make row as clickable as well buttons on cell that will be clickable.

I have tried using storyboard but it is not working.

Comment: So,what is your problem?Does you button not clickable?

Comment: it throws build error like illegal configuration. outlet can not be connected to repeating content.

Comment: Have you created a custom class for the cell ? If yes then post the code here.

Comment: Sorry no idea about this...as i am new in swift so.

Comment: add tag to buttons and labels...so you can use it in cell or make custom cell to objects in cell to get rid of `outlet can not be connected to repeating contents`

Comment: Please add more detail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is you drag a button directly to you UIViewController,that will not work. Because that is a prototype cell.

What you can do is

1. Set a tag for this button,for example 11
2. Add target in `cellForRowAtIndex`

   ```
   override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
   {
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
       let  button = cell.viewWithTag(11) as? UIButton
       if button != nil{
           button?.addTarget(self, action: "clicked:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
       }
       return cell
   }
   ```
3. Get button action and index

   ```
   func clicked(sender:UIButton){
      let point = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView:self.tableView)
       let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(point)
      println("Clicked \(indexPath!.row)")
   }
   ```

Comment: @Leo-i want to send cell reference to button action. i have tried this but it is not working. "button?.setValue(cellRef, forKey: "CELL")" and then get from action function "var cell: TestCell = sender.valueForKey("CELL") as! TestCell"

Comment: You can not do that. Because, `setValue` is based on KVC,and `UITableviewCell` does not have a property called "CELL"

Comment: Actually i want to pass parameters while calling action...any idea how to do.

Comment: You can not do that with UITableviewCell,you can do it with custom UITableviewCell class. Just goolge "iOS custom subclass of UITableviewCell"